# SharePoint Online Authorization cookie using _vti_bin/Authentication.asmx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I have a SharePoint site. This is a FBA site, and I have the Login.aspx page where I enter my user name/Password and I can login successfully. But, when I try to connect to the same service through Visual Studio/C# in order to get authorization cookie, it gives "Password Not Match" error.

```
 if (currentMode == AuthenticationMode.Forms)
 {
     try
     {
         //try to login with emali , 
         loginres = auth.Login(UserName, Password);
         throw new Exception("Go to catch section");
     }
     else
     {
         loginres = new LoginResult();
         loginres.ErrorCode = LoginErrorCode.NotInFormsAuthenticationMode;
     }
 }
```

Does the process have any prerequisite to get the cookie like a SQL Table with the Username and password ?